# type error on props, trying to send a boolean type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

i made this component

```
import * as Styled from './styles';

export type HeadingProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode | string;
  colorDark: boolean;
};

export const Heading = ({ children, colorDark }: HeadingProps) => {
  return <Styled.Wrapper colorDark={colorDark}>{children}</Styled.Wrapper>;
};
```

but the prop colorDark is giving an error

```
 The type '{ children: ReactNode; colorDark: boolean; }' cannot be assigned to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
```

someone know how do i solve this problem?

Comment: Hello. Show us what `Styled.Wrapper` is.

Comment: its a div export const Wrapper = styled.h1`
`;

Answer (score 0):

> its a div export const Wrapper = styled.h1 ;

Apparently you are missing types for the *styled* component.

```
export const Wrapper = styled.h1<{ colorDark: boolean }>`
   ...
`;
```